# How start with XUL development?

Tags: user-interface, themes, xul, thunderbird

First of all, I need to say that my English is not good. So I sorry for errors in this post.

Second, I'm a professional programmer for 2 years. Main programming language is VB.net (that I find somewhat limited when speaking about User Interfaces).

I love user interfaces, and I really want to be able to create software in Windows environment that has great User interface. After a long time searching for such a thing I discovered a Thunderbird theme that makes exactly what I want! This theme is called "[Leopard Mail-Default-Aqua](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/leopard-mail-default-aqua/)". This is really beautiful.

After some research I discovered that the Thunderbird UI is created using something called XUL, and that XUL is a descriptive language for user interfaces. Now I'm very interested in creating applications using this platform, but have no idea where to start.
After some research I also discovered that Microsoft created [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) to separate GUI from logic, and WPF support themes, but to me it's much more lucrative to learn XUL that is multiplatform, than WPF.

I need some directions on how to start development in XUL, and also very important, how can I use existing themes for Thunderbird in my XUL applications, so them look really great?

From what I've seen, applications developed in XUL uses javascript or C++ to program logic. Is this correct?

Also, as I came from .net programming that is event driven, I'd like to know if XUL development is also event driven, so if I want to respond to a button click for exemple, I can connect a event to a code/function.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think it's [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) you've been looking for, not XUL. There's plenty of [tutorials](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/tutorials.html) to get you started.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is accepted -- if he is looking at how Thunderbird was built, he's definitely looking for XUL.

Answer (score 7):

The best place to find XUL documentation is at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)  Here are some specific suggestion from MDN and other places:

- [Introduction to XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/introduction_to_xul)
- [XUL tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xul_tutorial) on the Mozilla Developer Center
- [XUL Periodic Chart](http://www.hevanet.com/acorbin/xul/top.xul) (Open in firefox, provides a demo of various XUL widgets)
- [XUL Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xul_explorer) (Provides a simple interface for learning XUL/building a XUL window)
- ## xul #xulrunner on [Mozilla's IRC channels](http://irc.mozilla.org/) (Low traffic but if you have a specific question you may be able to get a response here)
- [XUL mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.xul/topics)

And yes, XUL is event-driven, you attach events to buttons and other widgets and Javascript functions respond to the events.

Answer (score 2):

There is XUL documentation at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL